# How to get values from jsonObj?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a problem with outputting values ​​from jsonObj. If a given Product exists, it needs to write Amount for it. For example for Product 7318802U the Amount should be 5, for Product 7304773U Amount should be 1. When the Product is not exist in jsonObj Amount should be 0.

```
    var txt = [{"Product":"7318802U","Amount":"5"},{"Product":"7304773U","Amount":"1"}];
    
    var jsonObj = eval(txt);
    
    var Products = ["7318802U","7304773U","7212UCSS"];
    
    
    function _isContains(json, value) {
        let contains = false;
        Object.keys(json).some(key => {
            contains = typeof json[key] === 'object' ? _isContains(json[key], value) : json[key] === value;
             return contains;
        });
        return contains;
     }
     
     for(var i = 0; i<Products.length; i++)
     {
            if(_isContains(jsonObj, Products[i])) 
        {
            console.info(Products[i] + " exist")
          console.info("Amount: ") //???
        
        }
        else {
        console.info(Products[i] + " not exist")
        console.info("Amount: 0")
        }
     }
```

js fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/nvx68ysh/

Comment: `txt[i].Product` and `txt[i].Amount` also you can use `for(var x in txt[i]){alert(x+' : '+txt[i][x])}`

Comment: JSON is a string, JavaScript objects are objects. To get values from JSON, you `parse` it then get data from the properties.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var jsonObj = [{"Product":"7318802U","Amount":"5"},{"Product":"7304773U","Amount":"1"}];

var Products = ["7318802U","7304773U","7212UCSS"];
 
for(var i = 0; i<Products.length; i++) {
  let targetObj = jsonObj.find((v) => v.Product === Products[i]);
  if (targetObj) {
    console.info(Products[i] + " exist")
    console.info("Amount: " + targetObj.Amount);
  } else {
    console.info(Products[i] + " not exist")
    console.info("Amount: 0");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var txt = [{
  "Product": "7318802U",
  "Amount": "5"
}, {
  "Product": "7304773U",
  "Amount": "1"
}];

var jsonObj = txt;

var Products = ["7318802U", "7304773U", "7212UCSS"];


function _isContains(json, value) {
  let contains = false;
  Object.keys(json).some(key => {
    contains = typeof json[key] === 'object' ? _isContains(json[key], value) : json[key] === value;
    return contains;
  });
  return contains;
}

for (var i = 0; i < Products.length; i++) {
  if (_isContains(jsonObj, Products[i])) {
    console.info(Products[i] + " exist");
    console.info("Amount: " + txt.find(v => v['Product'] === Products[i])['Amount']);

  } else {
    console.info(Products[i] + " not exist")
    console.info("Amount: 0")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        function getProductByCode(code) {
            return txt.filter(
                function(data){ return data.Product == code }
            )[0];
        }

        var txt = [{"Product":"7318802U","Amount":"5"},{"Product":"7304773U","Amount":"1"}];
        
        var jsonObj = eval(txt);
        
        var Products = ["7318802U","7304773U","7212UCSS"];
        
        
        function _isContains(json, value) {
            let contains = false;
            Object.keys(json).some(key => {
                contains = typeof json[key] === 'object' ? _isContains(json[key], value) : json[key] === value;
                return contains;
            });
            return contains;
        }
        
        for(var i = 0; i<Products.length; i++)
        {
                if(_isContains(jsonObj, Products[i])) 
            {
                console.info(Products[i] + " exist")
                var u = getProductByCode(Products[i]).Amount;
                console.info("Amount: "+u )
            
            }
            else {
            console.info(Products[i] + " not exist")
            console.info("Amount: 0")
            }
        }
        
        
                //console.info(_isContains(jsonObj, "7318802U"));
```